# Сортировка композитного типа

Tags: postgresql

Существует композитный тип :

`CREATE TYPE public.value_telemetry AS
   (number integer,
    data character varying(1000));`

Есть переменная `data value_telemetry[];`

Как переменную data  отсортировать по  полю number в порядке возрастания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможное решение:

`data = 
( 
SELECT array_agg(x) From(SELECT unnest (data)as x  ORDER BY 1 ) as r
);`